# Deriving constraints for a linear system using orthonormal columns of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having some trouble understanding how the following was derived.

$H = \begin{bmatrix} h_1 & h_2 & h_3 \end{bmatrix}$ is a homography (not entirely sure what that entails)

$\begin{bmatrix} h_1 & h_2 & h_3 \end{bmatrix} = \lambda A\begin{bmatrix}r_1 & r_2 & t\end{bmatrix}$ where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary scalar.

Assume $r_1$ and $r_2$ are orthonormal because they form the columns of a rotation matrix. $t$ is a translation vector.

Now, they use this to derive the following two equations.

$h_1(A^{-1})^TA^{-1}h_2 = 0$

$h_1^T(A^{-1})^TA^{-1}h_1 = h_2^T(A^{-1})^TA^{-1}h_2$

I'm not sure how either of these were derived using rules about orthonormal columns. Please let me know if more information is required.

Reference: MSR-TR-98-71 "A Flexible New Technique for Camera Calibration, Zhengyou Zhang"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\small{\begin{bmatrix} h_1 & h_2 & h_3 \end{bmatrix}} = \lambda A\small{\begin{bmatrix}r_1 & r_2 & t\end{bmatrix}}$ you have $h_1=\lambda Ar_1$ and $h_2=\lambda Ar_2$. Presumably $\lambda\ne0$ and $A$ is invertible, so $r_1=1/\lambda\,A^{-1}h_1$ and $r_2=1/\lambda\,A^{-1}h_2$. The rest follows immediately from the orthonormality of $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Comment: Thanks! So I tried computing $r_1^Tr_2 = 0$ but shouldn't there be a $\frac{1}{\lambda ^2}$ term?

Comment: I'm guessing we just multiply by $\lambda$ on both sides and it goes away

Comment: @Carpetfizz Precisely.